# jquery carousel is acting wrong after updating jquery 1.4 to 1.8.2

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

I was using my slider perfectliy before updating jquery but after updating it 1.4 to 1.8.2 it started acting wrong. first and second pic is ok but after that images are starting to sliding more to left and leaving a space on the right which is growing by every change and than nothing remains. All images are same size as the first one(960x450).

Can i fix it if yes how or should i use a new one?

Here is html:

```
<div id="slider" class="box">
                        <div id="slider-holder">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#"><img class ="slider" src="css/images/slide1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><img class ="slider" src="css/images/slide2.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><img class ="slider" src="css/images/slide3.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><img class ="slider" src="css/images/slide4.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div id="slider-nav">
                                <a href="#" class="active">1</a>
                                <a href="#">2</a>
                                <a href="#">3</a>
                                <a href="#">4</a>
                        </div>
        </div>
```

Here is jquery but it is compressed:

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('(9($){$.1v.C=9(o){z 4.1b(9(){3p r(4,o)})};8 q={Z:F,25:1,21:1,u:7,1c:3,15:7,1K:\'2X\',2c:\'2Q\',1q:0,B:7,1j:7,1G:7,2F:7,2B:7,2z:7,2x:7,2v:7,2s:7,2p:7,1S:\'<P></P>\',1Q:\'<P></P>\',2m:\'2l\',2k:\'2l\',1O:7,1L:7};$.C=9(e,o){4.5=$.16({},q,o||{});4.Q=F;4.D=7;4.H=7;4.t=7;4.U=7;4.R=7;4.N=!4.5.Z?\'1H\':\'26\';4.E=!4.5.Z?\'24\':\'23\';8 a=\'\',1e=e.K.1e(\' \');1r(8 i=0;i<1e.I;i++){6(1e[i].2y(\'C-2w\')!=-1){$(e).1E(1e[i]);8 a=1e[i];1p}}6(e.2t==\'3o\'||e.2t==\'3n\'){4.t=$(e);4.D=4.t.19();6(4.D.1o(\'C-H\')){6(!4.D.19().1o(\'C-D\'))4.D=4.D.B(\'<P></P>\');4.D=4.D.19()}10 6(!4.D.1o(\'C-D\'))4.D=4.t.B(\'<P></P>\').19()}10{4.D=$(e);4.t=$(e).3h(\'>2o,>2n,P>2o,P>2n\')}6(a!=\'\'&&4.D.19()[0].K.2y(\'C-2w\')==-1)4.D.B(\'<P 3g=" \'+a+\'"></P>\');4.H=4.t.19();6(!4.H.I||!4.H.1o(\'C-H\'))4.H=4.t.B(\'<P></P>\').19();4.R=$(\'.C-11\',4.D);6(4.R.u()==0&&4.5.1Q!=7)4.R=4.H.1z(4.5.1Q).11();4.R.V(4.K(\'C-11\'));4.U=$(\'.C-17\',4.D);6(4.U.u()==0&&4.5.1S!=7)4.U=4.H.1z(4.5.1S).11();4.U.V(4.K(\'C-17\'));4.H.V(4.K(\'C-H\'));4.t.V(4.K(\'C-t\'));4.D.V(4.K(\'C-D\'));8 b=4.5.15!=7?1k.1P(4.1m()/4.5.15):7;8 c=4.t.32(\'1F\');8 d=4;6(c.u()>0){8 f=0,i=4.5.21;c.1b(9(){d.1I(4,i++);f+=d.S(4,b)});4.t.y(4.N,f+\'T\');6(!o||o.u===J)4.5.u=c.u()}4.D.y(\'1y\',\'1A\');4.U.y(\'1y\',\'1A\');4.R.y(\'1y\',\'1A\');4.2G=9(){d.17()};4.2b=9(){d.11()};4.1U=9(){d.2q()};6(4.5.1j!=7)4.5.1j(4,\'2a\');6($.2A.28){4.1f(F,F);$(27).1u(\'2I\',9(){d.1t()})}10 4.1t()};8 r=$.C;r.1v=r.2H={C:\'0.2.3\'};r.1v.16=r.16=$.16;r.1v.16({1t:9(){4.A=7;4.G=7;4.X=7;4.13=7;4.14=F;4.1d=7;4.O=7;4.W=F;6(4.Q)z;4.t.y(4.E,4.1s(4.5.21)+\'T\');8 p=4.1s(4.5.25);4.X=4.13=7;4.1i(p,F);$(27).22(\'2E\',4.1U).1u(\'2E\',4.1U)},2D:9(){4.t.2C();4.t.y(4.E,\'3u\');4.t.y(4.N,\'3t\');6(4.5.1j!=7)4.5.1j(4,\'2D\');4.1t()},2q:9(){6(4.O!=7&&4.W)4.t.y(4.E,r.M(4.t.y(4.E))+4.O);4.O=7;4.W=F;6(4.5.1G!=7)4.5.1G(4);6(4.5.15!=7){8 a=4;8 b=1k.1P(4.1m()/4.5.15),N=0,E=0;$(\'1F\',4.t).1b(9(i){N+=a.S(4,b);6(i+1<a.A)E=N});4.t.y(4.N,N+\'T\');4.t.y(4.E,-E+\'T\')}4.1c(4.A,F)},3s:9(){4.Q=1h;4.1f()},3r:9(){4.Q=F;4.1f()},u:9(s){6(s!=J){4.5.u=s;6(!4.Q)4.1f()}z 4.5.u},3q:9(i,a){6(a==J||!a)a=i;6(4.5.u!==7&&a>4.5.u)a=4.5.u;1r(8 j=i;j<=a;j++){8 e=4.L(j);6(!e.I||e.1o(\'C-1a-1D\'))z F}z 1h},L:9(i){z $(\'.C-1a-\'+i,4.t)},2u:9(i,s){8 e=4.L(i),20=0,2u=0;6(e.I==0){8 c,e=4.1B(i),j=r.M(i);1n(c=4.L(--j)){6(j<=0||c.I){j<=0?4.t.2r(e):c.1X(e);1p}}}10 20=4.S(e);e.1E(4.K(\'C-1a-1D\'));1R s==\'3l\'?e.3k(s):e.2C().3j(s);8 a=4.5.15!=7?1k.1P(4.1m()/4.5.15):7;8 b=4.S(e,a)-20;6(i>0&&i<4.A)4.t.y(4.E,r.M(4.t.y(4.E))-b+\'T\');4.t.y(4.N,r.M(4.t.y(4.N))+b+\'T\');z e},1V:9(i){8 e=4.L(i);6(!e.I||(i>=4.A&&i<=4.G))z;8 d=4.S(e);6(i<4.A)4.t.y(4.E,r.M(4.t.y(4.E))+d+\'T\');e.1V();4.t.y(4.N,r.M(4.t.y(4.N))-d+\'T\')},17:9(){4.1C();6(4.O!=7&&!4.W)4.1T(F);10 4.1c(((4.5.B==\'1Z\'||4.5.B==\'G\')&&4.5.u!=7&&4.G==4.5.u)?1:4.A+4.5.1c)},11:9(){4.1C();6(4.O!=7&&4.W)4.1T(1h);10 4.1c(((4.5.B==\'1Z\'||4.5.B==\'A\')&&4.5.u!=7&&4.A==1)?4.5.u:4.A-4.5.1c)},1T:9(b){6(4.Q||4.14||!4.O)z;8 a=r.M(4.t.y(4.E));!b?a-=4.O:a+=4.O;4.W=!b;4.X=4.A;4.13=4.G;4.1i(a)},1c:9(i,a){6(4.Q||4.14)z;4.1i(4.1s(i),a)},1s:9(i){6(4.Q||4.14)z;6(4.5.B!=\'18\')i=i<1?1:(4.5.u&&i>4.5.u?4.5.u:i);8 a=4.A>i;8 b=r.M(4.t.y(4.E));8 f=4.5.B!=\'18\'&&4.A<=1?1:4.A;8 c=a?4.L(f):4.L(4.G);8 j=a?f:f-1;8 e=7,l=0,p=F,d=0;1n(a?--j>=i:++j<i){e=4.L(j);p=!e.I;6(e.I==0){e=4.1B(j).V(4.K(\'C-1a-1D\'));c[a?\'1z\':\'1X\'](e)}c=e;d=4.S(e);6(p)l+=d;6(4.A!=7&&(4.5.B==\'18\'||(j>=1&&(4.5.u==7||j<=4.5.u))))b=a?b+d:b-d}8 g=4.1m();8 h=[];8 k=0,j=i,v=0;8 c=4.L(i-1);1n(++k){e=4.L(j);p=!e.I;6(e.I==0){e=4.1B(j).V(4.K(\'C-1a-1D\'));c.I==0?4.t.2r(e):c[a?\'1z\':\'1X\'](e)}c=e;8 d=4.S(e);6(d==0){3f(\'3e: 3d 1H/26 3c 1r 3b. 3a 39 38 37 36 35. 34...\');z 0}6(4.5.B!=\'18\'&&4.5.u!==7&&j>4.5.u)h.33(e);10 6(p)l+=d;v+=d;6(v>=g)1p;j++}1r(8 x=0;x<h.I;x++)h[x].1V();6(l>0){4.t.y(4.N,4.S(4.t)+l+\'T\');6(a){b-=l;4.t.y(4.E,r.M(4.t.y(4.E))-l+\'T\')}}8 n=i+k-1;6(4.5.B!=\'18\'&&4.5.u&&n>4.5.u)n=4.5.u;6(j>n){k=0,j=n,v=0;1n(++k){8 e=4.L(j--);6(!e.I)1p;v+=4.S(e);6(v>=g)1p}}8 o=n-k+1;6(4.5.B!=\'18\'&&o<1)o=1;6(4.W&&a){b+=4.O;4.W=F}4.O=7;6(4.5.B!=\'18\'&&n==4.5.u&&(n-k+1)>=1){8 m=r.Y(4.L(n),!4.5.Z?\'1l\':\'1N\');6((v-m)>g)4.O=v-g-m}1n(i-->o)b+=4.S(4.L(i));4.X=4.A;4.13=4.G;4.A=o;4.G=n;z b},1i:9(p,a){6(4.Q||4.14)z;4.14=1h;8 b=4;8 c=9(){b.14=F;6(p==0)b.t.y(b.E,0);6(b.5.B==\'1Z\'||b.5.B==\'G\'||b.5.u==7||b.G<b.5.u)b.2j();b.1f();b.1M(\'2i\')};4.1M(\'31\');6(!4.5.1K||a==F){4.t.y(4.E,p+\'T\');c()}10{8 o=!4.5.Z?{\'24\':p}:{\'23\':p};4.t.1i(o,4.5.1K,4.5.2c,c)}},2j:9(s){6(s!=J)4.5.1q=s;6(4.5.1q==0)z 4.1C();6(4.1d!=7)z;8 a=4;4.1d=30(9(){a.17()},4.5.1q*2Z)},1C:9(){6(4.1d==7)z;2Y(4.1d);4.1d=7},1f:9(n,p){6(n==J||n==7){8 n=!4.Q&&4.5.u!==0&&((4.5.B&&4.5.B!=\'A\')||4.5.u==7||4.G<4.5.u);6(!4.Q&&(!4.5.B||4.5.B==\'A\')&&4.5.u!=7&&4.G>=4.5.u)n=4.O!=7&&!4.W}6(p==J||p==7){8 p=!4.Q&&4.5.u!==0&&((4.5.B&&4.5.B!=\'G\')||4.A>1);6(!4.Q&&(!4.5.B||4.5.B==\'G\')&&4.5.u!=7&&4.A==1)p=4.O!=7&&4.W}8 a=4;4.U[n?\'1u\':\'22\'](4.5.2m,4.2G)[n?\'1E\':\'V\'](4.K(\'C-17-1w\')).1J(\'1w\',n?F:1h);4.R[p?\'1u\':\'22\'](4.5.2k,4.2b)[p?\'1E\':\'V\'](4.K(\'C-11-1w\')).1J(\'1w\',p?F:1h);6(4.U.I>0&&(4.U[0].1g==J||4.U[0].1g!=n)&&4.5.1O!=7){4.U.1b(9(){a.5.1O(a,4,n)});4.U[0].1g=n}6(4.R.I>0&&(4.R[0].1g==J||4.R[0].1g!=p)&&4.5.1L!=7){4.R.1b(9(){a.5.1L(a,4,p)});4.R[0].1g=p}},1M:9(a){8 b=4.X==7?\'2a\':(4.X<4.A?\'17\':\'11\');4.12(\'2F\',a,b);6(4.X!==4.A){4.12(\'2B\',a,b,4.A);4.12(\'2z\',a,b,4.X)}6(4.13!==4.G){4.12(\'2x\',a,b,4.G);4.12(\'2v\',a,b,4.13)}4.12(\'2s\',a,b,4.A,4.G,4.X,4.13);4.12(\'2p\',a,b,4.X,4.13,4.A,4.G)},12:9(a,b,c,d,e,f,g){6(4.5[a]==J||(1R 4.5[a]!=\'2h\'&&b!=\'2i\'))z;8 h=1R 4.5[a]==\'2h\'?4.5[a][b]:4.5[a];6(!$.2W(h))z;8 j=4;6(d===J)h(j,c,b);10 6(e===J)4.L(d).1b(9(){h(j,4,d,c,b)});10{1r(8 i=d;i<=e;i++)6(i!==7&&!(i>=f&&i<=g))4.L(i).1b(9(){h(j,4,i,c,b)})}},1B:9(i){z 4.1I(\'<1F></1F>\',i)},1I:9(e,i){8 a=$(e).V(4.K(\'C-1a\')).V(4.K(\'C-1a-\'+i));a.1J(\'2V\',i);z a},K:9(c){z c+\' \'+c+(!4.5.Z?\'-2U\':\'-Z\')},S:9(e,d){8 a=e.2g!=J?e[0]:e;8 b=!4.5.Z?a.1x+r.Y(a,\'2f\')+r.Y(a,\'1l\'):a.2e+r.Y(a,\'2d\')+r.Y(a,\'1N\');6(d==J||b==d)z b;8 w=!4.5.Z?d-r.Y(a,\'2f\')-r.Y(a,\'1l\'):d-r.Y(a,\'2d\')-r.Y(a,\'1N\');$(a).y(4.N,w+\'T\');z 4.S(a)},1m:9(){z!4.5.Z?4.H[0].1x-r.M(4.H.y(\'2T\'))-r.M(4.H.y(\'2S\')):4.H[0].2e-r.M(4.H.y(\'2R\'))-r.M(4.H.y(\'3i\'))},2P:9(i,s){6(s==J)s=4.5.u;z 1k.2O((((i-1)/s)-1k.2N((i-1)/s))*s)+1}});r.16({3m:9(d){z $.16(q,d||{})},Y:9(e,p){6(!e)z 0;8 a=e.2g!=J?e[0]:e;6(p==\'1l\'&&$.2A.28){8 b={\'1y\':\'1A\',\'2M\':\'2L\',\'1H\':\'1q\'},1Y,1W;$.29(a,b,9(){1Y=a.1x});b[\'1l\']=0;$.29(a,b,9(){1W=a.1x});z 1W-1Y}z r.M($.y(a,p))},M:9(v){v=2K(v);z 2J(v)?0:v}})})(3v);',62,218,'||||this|options|if|null|var|function||||||||||||||||||||list|size||||css|return|first|wrap|jcarousel|container|lt|false|last|clip|length|undefined|className|get|intval|wh|tail|div|locked|buttonPrev|dimension|px|buttonNext|addClass|inTail|prevFirst|margin|vertical|else|prev|callback|prevLast|animating|visible|extend|next|circular|parent|item|each|scroll|timer|split|buttons|jcarouselstate|true|animate|initCallback|Math|marginRight|clipping|while|hasClass|break|auto|for|pos|setup|bind|fn|disabled|offsetWidth|display|before|block|create|stopAuto|placeholder|removeClass|li|reloadCallback|width|format|attr|animation|buttonPrevCallback|notify|marginBottom|buttonNextCallback|ceil|buttonPrevHTML|typeof|buttonNextHTML|scrollTail|funcResize|remove|oWidth2|after|oWidth|both|old|offset|unbind|top|left|start|height|window|safari|swap|init|funcPrev|easing|marginTop|offsetHeight|marginLeft|jquery|object|onAfterAnimation|startAuto|buttonPrevEvent|click|buttonNextEvent|ol|ul|itemVisibleOutCallback|reload|prepend|itemVisibleInCallback|nodeName|add|itemLastOutCallback|skin|itemLastInCallback|indexOf|itemFirstOutCallback|browser|itemFirstInCallback|empty|reset|resize|itemLoadCallback|funcNext|prototype|load|isNaN|parseInt|none|float|floor|round|index|swing|borderTopWidth|borderRightWidth|borderLeftWidth|horizontal|jcarouselindex|isFunction|normal|clearTimeout|1000|setTimeout|onBeforeAnimation|children|push|Aborting|loop|infinite|an|cause|will|This|items|set|No|jCarousel|alert|class|find|borderBottomWidth|append|html|string|defaults|OL|UL|new|has|unlock|lock|10px|0px|jQuery'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

css:

```
    #slider { height:252px; position:relative; overflow:hidden; }
#slider-holder { width:720px; height:252px; position:relative; overflow:hidden; }
#slider-holder .jcarousel-clip{ width:720px; height:252px; position:relative; overflow:hidden; }
#slider-holder ul{ width:720px; height:252px; position:relative; overflow:hidden; list-style-type: none;}
#slider-holder ul li{ width:720px; height:252px; position:relative; overflow:hidden; float:left; }

#slider-nav { position:absolute; top:231px; left:644px; z-index:2;}
#slider-nav a{ font-size:0; line-height:0; text-indent: -4000px; width:10px; height:10px; border:solid 1px #8b0000; background:#8b0000; float:left; margin-right:5px; }
#slider-nav a:hover,
#slider-nav a.active { background:#fff;}
```

Comment: which jquery carousel plugin are you using?

Comment: Did you try updating your plugins to latest version?

Comment: I couldn't find a new version.

Comment: Then try a different carousel, one that's updated frequently. There are many ok, like Nivo, Agile Carousel, Coin...